# Is the "Publicist" badge broken?

Tags: support, badges

I have been seeing this dialog (see image) frequently, and when I go and share the question on facebook or twitter, it does not do anything.

Not that I am crazy about the badge, but I wonder if it is actually working.

[image: publicist bug]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sharing a link to the question does not necessarily mean you will earn the Publicist badge. 25 visits from unique IP addresses will give you the **Announcer** badge, 300 the **Booster** badge, and 1000 the **Publicist** badge.

Comment: Don't forget, there's also a requirement that those visits occur in a span of time (3, 4, and 5 days respectively). Furthermore, if I'm not mistaken the message will stop showing up once you've earned your Announcer badge.

Comment: So the message above means the question might be a candidate and probably not yet visited 1000 times, right?

Comment: @Bora No: the same question is capable of producing the badge multiple times from different users. What it means is that the user hasn't gotten the badge yet, as a user can only earn one of each.

Comment: @Bora, another restriction is that visits from within the SE network (if the link was clicked in another SE site) are ignored.